# Help finding a laser that will pulse with my signal generator

Tags: laser, home-experiment, laser-interaction

When I connect my 5mW red laser to my signal generator the laser fails to deliver clear square wave pulses once I go below the 2000ns mark.

The signal generator is capable of producing pulses as low as 25ns. When I skip the laser and the 10ns diode and send the signal directly to the oscilloscope I get a pretty good signal in the 25ns range. The square wave is rounded a little but not bad.

I have tried different lasers. TTL setups don’t seem to produce much of an improvement. All of my lasers are the inexpensive variety, the ones you can find on eBay for about five dollars. I am willing to spend more if I thought I would get better results.

Any ideas on a laser that would work? The photodiodes I use have a rise time of 10ns and I operate them in reverse bias. I am a hobbyists who does at home experiments so please keep that in mind.

Any thoughts on the topic are appreciated.

Comment: The RP Photonics Encyclopedia [Pulsed Lasers](https://www.rp-photonics.com/pulsed_lasers.html) page might help.

Comment: What do you modulate with the function generator? The gain power? Or something which  changes the $Q$ of the laser resonator?

Comment: @A.P. The function generator has a pulse mode in which it delivers a changing voltage to the laser diode. The only Q switching would be a loss of power. I think that the 5mW may be too small. The pulsed light become too dim for the diode to detect accurately.

Comment: uffff...you are in a rabbit hole if you want to modulate at MHz freqs...First you should modulate current. Try to have your LOW as $I_{th}$ and modulate like that, see if that improves... However not every diode laser can be modulated in the ns scale. Companies like picoquant, who manufacture high frequency modulation diodes, spends a lot of time and resources just purchasing and testing diodes to see if they can be modulated or not.